# Why is this view-model string field treated as required?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, nullable-reference-types

I have a simple login page with the view model below.  It used to work just fine, but seemingly suddenly, `ModelState` will contain an error for the `ReturnUrl` field if it wasn't supplied to the action.  It states, "The ReturnUrl field is required."

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = TextValidation.RequiredErrorMessage)]
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = TextValidation.RequiredErrorMessage)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Why would it do that for a `string` field (i.e. nullable) that does not have a `[Required]` annotation?

Here's the beginning of the controller action that makes use of that model.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();  // <-- It returns here.
    }
    ...
}
```

If I debug, I see the following:

```
ModelState.Results[2].Key = "ReturnUrl"
ModelState.Results[2].Value.AttemptedValue = null
ModelState.Results[2].Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage = "The ReturnUrl field is required."
```

One more detail I can add is that I have the same model and action in another project, and in that project, it works fine.  If I debug the Login action in that project, I see that `ModelState.Results` only contains 2 elements: "Username" and "Password".  The third element ("ReturnUrl") is not there, which is what I would expect since it shouldn't be getting validated.

Comment: Hi @MarredCheese, please share more code. Did you custom validation or not? Only share the model could not be helpful.

Comment: @Rena I added the action and debug info.  No, there's nothing custom.

Comment: is it MVC + EF Core?

Comment: It's .NET Core 3.1, MVC, no EF (using Dapper instead).

Comment: I'm guessing you recently made a change that enabled nullable reference types, and ASP.NET is deciding that because that value is non nullable, it's required.

Comment: @sellotape Yep, you were right.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, reference types had been set to non-nullable for the project.  I don't know how it happened, but in `<Project>.csproj`, there was this entry:

```
<Nullable>annotations</Nullable>
```

Here's more info on the 4 options for that field:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

If you delete the entry, you get the default: `disable`.  And note that these nullability contexts can also be controlled at the file or line level via `#nullable <context>`.  The above link covers that as well.

If I had to guess, I'd say I must have misclicked while viewing Visual Studio's graphical interface for the project's properties:

[image: properties]

Comment: it's actually pretty good to have this enabled and be explicit about it

Answer (score 1):

In latest versions of .NET, you have to declare string as nullable (string?) or change project build properties to accept strings as nullable.